# Запрос копирования данных с условием

Tags: sql

Есть таблицы `content` и `contentvalues`. Необходимо скопировать данные из одной таблицы в другую. БД одна, но столбцы разные.

Нужно из таблицы `content`, строки, `ID` которых равны `content_id` в таблице `contentvalues`, скопировать поле `content.longtitle` в поле `contentvalues.value`. Изменять только строки, `tmplvarid` которых равен 13.

Делал так, но выдает ошибку:

```sql
update contentvalues, content
set contentvalues.value=content.longtitle
where contentvalues.tmplvarid=13;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
merge into contentvalues cval using content src
on (cval.content_id = src.id)
when matched then 
    update set cval.value = src.longtitle 
    where cval.tmplvarid = 13
;
```

Можете добавить - `when not matched then insert ...`, если подозреваете, что строчкa ещё не существует.